# Sharing an audio file using intent

Tags: android, file, share

This is my code:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///"+filePath));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

**Problem** : For some reason, when I checked today this code on `nexus 5X API 26` emulator, the app crashes whereas 
on my `Xperia z5 premium`(*api 25*) it works like a charm.

Is there a chance this code not compatible with the new api?

logcat-

```
08-24 15:16:08.445 3050-3050/com.example.tsuryohananov.mycallrecorder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.tsuryohananov.mycallrecorder, PID: 3050
                                                                                    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:////storage/emulated/0/CallRecordings/24.08.2017  02-32-19 PM.m4a exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                                                                                        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1932)
                                                                                        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2348)
                                                                                        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:941)
                                                                                        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9735)
                                                                                        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9741)
                                                                                        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9720)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1609)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4471)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4429)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4788)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4756)
                                                                                        at com.example.tsuryohananov.mycallrecorder.MainActivity$9.onClick(MainActivity.java:324)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

(line 324 is startActivity)

Comment: Can you post your LogCat for crashing device?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: @Orkun Koçyiğit posting

Comment: @Orkun Koçyiğit posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is already mentioned in the logcat.
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:////storage/emulated/0/CallRecordings/24.08.2017  02-32-19 PM.m4a exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

There are two ways to solve this problem.

1. Put the following code

   `StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());`

in `Application.onCreate().`

we will simply change the VmPolicy by the above method. In this way VM will ignore the exposure URI exposure. Default method is

```
builder.detectFileUriExposure()
```

which checks the file for exposure.

2. Instead of file:// try using content://
   In later android version starting from 24 we have to use `FileProvider` class so that the files are accessible for other apps as well.

I hope it helps, For more on converting from 
`file://` to `content://`

refer this Question -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040